# How to use Blender Python script on Windows Container?

Tags: scripting, windows

I tried to use on Windows container by using the following "Dockerfile" and "script.py".

I used this script.py and blender.exe and it was working on local PC with Windows 10.

But, I used "Dockerfile" & "script.py" on Docker and it does not work. There are no files to output on container. It seems Blender on container does not work.(Windows host, OS is Windows Server 2019)

## Dockerfile

```
# Base FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Download Blender URL ARG BLENDER_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.93/blender-2.93.0-windows-x64.zip

# Work directory WORKDIR C:/blender

# Download Blender RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:BLENDER_DOWNLOAD_URL -OutFile 'blender.zip'; \
    Expand-Archive -Path 'blender.zip' -DestinationPath '.' -Force; \
    Remove-Item -Path 'blender.zip' -Force

# Add PATH RUN setx /M PATH $('C:/blender/blender-windows64;' + $env:PATH)

# Script COPY script.py .

CMD ["blender.exe", "-b", "-P", "script.py"]
```

## script.py

```
import bpy 
import os

for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(location = (-5, -5, 0), size = 3.0)

output_filename = "output.stl"

output_dir = "C:/work/blenderAPI"

output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)

bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=output_path)

bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```